# Explaining Arrays - connecting to specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning JavaScript at the moment and I am doing some exercise about arrays. I cant understand how "user" from the code below accesing all "username" from every object in array.

Here is an example of my array:

```
//array
const array = [{
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];

//exercise where I cant undestand how user parameter acces username from objects

const filterArray = array.filter(user => {
  return user.team === "red";
})

console.log(filterArray);
```

Comment: The `user` parameter will be, in succession, each element of the original array. Because the elements are objects, `user` will be one of those objects each time the function is called by `.filter()`.

Comment: See docs about [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The callback receives each array element as its first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation for [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

In your code, `user` is an argument to the callback function of `filter`. JavaScript invokes this function with each element of the array, and hence `user` receives all the details of items in your array.

Answer (score 1):

The `.filter` method will iterate over each element in an array one by one and will apply the function that you give to it (`user => user.team === 'red'` in your case) in order to determine whether that element should be in the resulting array or not.

Think of it as a built-in way of writing:

```
function filter(array){
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].team === 'red'){
        result.push(array[i]);
    }           
  }
  return result;
}
```